# Performance of Google Firebase Database Admin SDK API vs REST API

Tags: performance, rest, firebase, sdk, firebase-realtime-database

I have the option to either use Firebase Admin SDK API or REST API to perform GET,PUT,POST & DELETE operations on my domain objects stored in firebase database.

Although, I do not have the full fledged performance numbers for REST vs SDK, however based on the operation I have done its appears operations performed using SDK is slower in comparison to REST API. The REST API response is faster because its a synchronous response whereas with SDK you need to register the listener and then you get the response asynchronously. 
Is my understanding correct?

Performance is my major concern and hence what to select the option using which I get faster response.
Which option should I use? can someone suggest based on their experience.

Comment: Without seeing what you tested and how you tested it, it is impossible to say anything.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen : you are the developer at firebase, maybe you should help us with the performance number and accordingly suggest which one is faster?
Assume you have to fetch data using either firebase SDK or firebase REST API, which one will you chose considering the performance of both?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Rest Api does not use Web Sockets or a persistent connection to listen for changes however the SDK use Web Sockets to establish a persistent connection from the client to the server. So depending on what you are doing if you need a real time observation of changes in data sets then you should go for the SDK.